# How can I scan from Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: scanning, microsoft-word-2010

I couldn't find the scan option in Microsoft Word 2010  but in Microsoft Word 2007 I used to have that option.

Can you please tell me how to scan from Microsoft Word 2010?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature that has been removed - [TechNet Article Changes in Word 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179199.aspx).

> MODI provided a common document imaging and scanning solution for Office. It was also the basis of the Fax feature for Office. When MODI was installed, it was the default handler for .tif, .tiff, and .mdi files. In Office 2010, MODI is fully deprecated. This change also affects the setup tree, which no longer shows the MODI Help, OCR, or Indexing Service Filter nodes on the Tools menu. The Internet Fax feature in Office 2010 uses the Windows Fax printer driver to generate a fixed file format (TIF). MODI and all its components are deprecated for 64-bit Office 2010.

Searches on the internet show some various work arounds to be using OneNote 2010 to scan/insert into Word, a Word macro or scan using scanner software and inserting into Word.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have not actually removed the facility, only the means of getting there.  A macro is freely available to restore the scan as an image function.

If you have omnipage just open it and go to tools/options and register the Winword .exe file (very intuitive) and then when you restart Word go to the tab marked 'Add ins' and you will find the OmniPage options (the old aquire text dialogue) you will be able to OCR as normal directly into the document - This applies to MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The link may be helpful in resolving this issue, you can add a button scan.

http://www.pcpro.co.uk/realworld/360373/how-to-scan-into-word-2010/2